# CopyFile() copy from network drive to local drive in windows 10

Tags: c++builder, file-copying

I'm using Rad Studio for running C++ in window 10.

I've been trying to copy a file from network drive to local drive.

When I tried to copy a file from local to local, it worked!

But when I tried to copy a file from server or mapped driver(Z:),
there are no error, not copied.

So it's hard to find the problem.

I guess that most do need some sort of authentication.

but I'm still stuck with it.

Here is my code.

```
String source = L"\\\\sever1\\Data\\program1.exe"; // Server to Local : result==> Not copied, no error.
// What I tried to test.
//   String source = L"E:\\file1\\083\\program1.exe";     //Local to Local : result==> It works!
//   String source = L"Z:\\program1.exe";         //mapped driver : result==> Not copied, no error.
String destination = L"C:\\Our Programs\\program1.exe";
result = CopyFile( source.w_str(), destination.w_str(), true);
```

Comment: If the source file cannot be found, or the destination cannot be written, you should be getting a `CopyFile` error. Assuming you check the `result` and it indicates success, try temporarily turning (completely) off any antivirus that you may have running.

Comment: CopyFile is using the Windows API - you can check errors and parameters passed.  It will attempt to use the standard network client library so it will attempt access using the user the program is running as.

Comment: `CopyFile()` returns 0 on failure and non-zero on success. If 0, `GetLastError()` will return why it failed. The code above is not checking that.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you for your reply. i'm going to try turning off antivirus i'm running.